# Looking for a verb that describes the movement of a breeze

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs, synonyms, vocabulary

I am looking for a word that descibes how a breeze travells over a beach.

It it was a wind, it could be blowing over the beach, past the rocks and gras, but blowing seems too fast for a breeze. My Intention is to convey a sense of movement, but more gentle and less directional then "blowing".

Could a breeze be roaming the beach?

Usage:

> The coastal winds were still asleep and only a soft breeze was gently (roaming?) the beach.

Comment: Would you consider it too tautological to say that the breeze _breezed_ over the beach?

Comment: I think technically that could work, but aesthetically I don't like it. It's just not my style. Thank you for the Suggestion tough. Keep em coming ;)

Comment: You could always go all poetic and say that “only a soft breeze gently caressed the beach”. Not exactly a synonym for the verb _breeze_, but poetic and (I think) quite nice.

Comment: There's always "waft".  Or one of its [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/waft).

Comment: @Hot Licks: Quite. I think just as [*all **petrels** are **stormy,** and all **dudgeon** is **high***](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm), we could probably say *all **breezes waft***.

Comment: @HotLicks [cough]  Technically, ["waft"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/waft) connotes "carrying" or "conveying" _on_ a breeze. Aromas and sound are wafted by a breeze or other medium.

Comment: @ HotLicks: Thank you, I quite like the whafting. Incidentally there is a smell, that I wanted to talk bout later, but the breeze can very well whaft it at this Point :)

Comment: @ FumbleFIngers: Thank you very much, I didn't know about stormy petrels. This opens a whole other can of worms, but I think that deserves a seperate question. :)

Comment: Rather than trying to find a verb for the breeze, describe its effect on the grass. That gives you an evocative, visual image.

Comment: Avoid asking for items, ideas, or opinions. Subjective questions will be closed unless the request is expert-level, unique, particularly interesting and thought-provoking, shows substantial effort and research, and demands responses that meet these same standards. See: “[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen figurative usage of "breeze caressing (something)" and I believe it fits in your sample sentence too.

> The coastal winds were still asleep and only a soft breeze was gently
>   ***caressing*** the beach.

ODO:

> **[caress](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/caress)**
>
> *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Touch or stroke gently or lovingly.
>
> *figurative* ‘a gentle breeze caressed his skin’

Comment: I didn't think there'd be an answer I'd be happy with here. This fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> When, lo, the dying breeze begins to fail,
>   and **flutters** on the mast, the flagging sail -

[Pharsalia Book V - The Works of the British Poets](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=trdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA13-PA789&dq=breeze+flutters&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjiJGlz7nYAhXlA8AKHS6YD0w4HhDoAQhQMAg#v=onepage&q=breeze%20flutters&f=false)

> The cool breeze from the sea **flutters** their drooping petals

[An Island Garden](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=v6mWkfwO_SsC&pg=PA105&dq=breeze+flutters&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjiJGlz7nYAhXlA8AKHS6YD0w4HhDoAQhVMAk#v=onepage&q=breeze%20flutters&f=false)

> How silently the breeze moves on, **flutters** and whispers and moves on -

[The Etonian Volume 3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NWEuAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA286&dq=breeze+flutters&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJg6uN0bnYAhVBWhQKHTjTBow4KBDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=breeze%20flutters&f=false)